# Lightweight reverse http proxy with websocket support

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, pound

does there exist a lightweight (when I tried apache it ate several hundred megs of memory) reverse http proxy which supports websockets?

I was so far using pound which does not support websockets but now I want to add a backend which needs websockets to work.

I considered nginx which I currently use in all of my backends and offers webproxy support. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to disable buffering of http requests with nginx. So file uploading will never be "streamed" to the backend but be cached by nginx first.

I dont need load balancing or caching and SSL termination is only a nice-to-have.

Which http reverse proxy gives me websocket support as well as "streaming" of http requests?

Comment: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/251

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, that's the bug that prevents nginx from being useful for me

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [TinyProxy](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinyproxy). It's lightweight, and I don't think it actually does any caching. It can also be configured as a reverse proxy.

Not sure if it is suitable for websockets, though...

Comment: TinyProxy only allows to decide by the path and not by the hostname where to proxy requests to. This makes it impossible to use TinyProxy as a reverse proxy for multiple hostnames.

Comment: @josch It is possible via the upstream directives

Comment: @MikeGleasonjrCouturier the discussion is moot because TinyProxy doesn't support websockets: https://github.com/tinyproxy/tinyproxy/issues/101